# Codeigniter beginner question (PHP Notice undefined variable)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

i have a beginner question.

Im making a video site.

I store the data in my database about the videos.

And i have a bit of a problem.

I would like to load the video embed by title and im doing something wrong.

the model

```
function load_video()
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('videos', array('title' => $title), 1);
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($q->result() as $row) {
            $vids[] = $row;
        }
        return $vids;
    }


}
```

here is the main page view, and the anchore wich i sopose to click it would show the video

```
foreach ($results as $r) {

        echo '<div class="video_box">';
            echo '<p>' . substr($r->title, 0, 16) . "..." . " </p>";
            $thumbnail = array('src' => $r->thumbnail, 'title' => $r->title,);
            echo "<a href='index.php/video/play/".$r->title."'>" . img($thumbnail) . "</a>";
            echo '<div class="duration">'.(round($r->duration / 60)).':' . ''.(round($r->duration % 60)).'</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

and here is the video controller

```
function play($title){
        $this->load->model('video_model');
        $data['results'] = $this->video_model->load_video();
        $this->load->view("video_page", $data);
    }
```

and im always getting this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: title

Filename: models/video_model.php

Line Number: 49

could please someone point out what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont load the variable/string inside your model?

If you use it in your database query yo should also send it? :)

In controller send it to model:

```
    $this->video_model->load_video($title);
```

In model we include it in the function:

```
    function load_video($title)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, i feel really dumb, and thanks for spearing time on my question

Comment: Everybody makes syntax errors.. or i sure hope - cause i make alot! Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes find it in seconds, while you would have to look for hours to find ones own errors! <3 Stackoverflow! :D